# Diodes in parallel circuit analysis

Tags: diodes, logic-gates

[image]

Could some please help me understand why D2 is on and not D1 on a) and why is D1 is on and not D2 for b). This is for ideal diodes

Comment: In a, D2 will turn in first because of the highes voltage. This creates a 0.6v drop or so across it. With this, the voltage across D1 is 0.4v which is not enough for it to conduct.

Comment: D1 _really_ won't be on, since the 0.4 V is reverse bias.

Comment: Ah, yes, ofcourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at A and given that your question mentions ideal. So an ideal diode has a Vf = 0. Any voltage greater than 0 will pass through the diode, and any voltage less than 0 will be stopped.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqBdyK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are 4 possible cases. 
case 1: D1 = off D2 = off
case 2: D1 = off D2 = on
case 3: D1 = on D2 = off
case 4: D1 = on D2 = on

If we assume case 1 is true. Then the math math behind it should show that we are right.
If D1 and D2 are off, that means that the voltage between anode and cathode must be negative.

$$ V_{d1 anode} - V_{d1 cathode} <= 0 $$
$$  +1V - (-5V) = 6V $$

The same can be done with D2
$$ V_{d2 anode} - V_{d2 cathode} <= 0 $$
$$  +2V - (-5V) = 7V $$

But in order for the diodes to be OFF, \$ V_{anode} - V_{cathode} <= 0 \$, but this is a contradiction with our assumption. So both diodes are not off.

Our guess was wrong. So lets try another one of the cases.

Let's assume that case 2 is correct.
So this means that the +2V passes straight through the diode. So the node at Vout is 2V.

$$ V_{d1 anode} - V_{d1 cathode} <= 0 $$
$$  +1V - (2) = -1V $$

This works. Case 2 is the answer.

Let's just see what happens with case 3.
This means that D1 is on, so the 1V passes straight through D1 and +1V is at the Vout node.

$$ V_{d2 anode} - V_{d2 cathode} <= 0 $$
$$  +2V - (+1V) = 1 $$

This is a contradiction to our initial guess that D2 is off. So this case is incorrect.

With some intuition and some experience, you can more or less "guess" the correct diode state and then just quickly verify that the math holds.

The same can be applied to your other circuit.

When you deal with non ideal diodes, then the diode will switch on, when the voltage between anode and cathode is greater than 0.7V.

Comment: I was wondering how come the -5 volt doesn't seem to play a role in this? Is it due to the resistor, so the current doesn't flow in that direction?

Comment: For the purpose of your original question. It does not matter. If the resistor was tied to ground, it would have the same effect. But if the circuit was designed to have a certain input range, then the -5V would play a factor. With -5V tied to the resistor, your input range for the diode(s) to conduct is Vinput > -5V (for the ideal case). You can think of the voltage died to the resistor as the bias voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a diode as a battery voltage drop when forward conducting. So in a), D2 forces V to 2-~0.7 volts where 0.7V is about the junction voltage of a diode. So V is raised to about 1.3V. That makes D1 reverse biased now so it won't conduct.

b) is just the opposite in topology. If a diode is treated like a battery voltage drop of about 0.7V then V is either 1.7V or 2.7V. If it was 2.7V, then you would have 1.7V dropping across D1 which either means you have infinite current or the diode just drops it back down to only 0.7V across itself. In this case, the diode just drops down to 0.7 which makes V=1.7V which reverse biases D2.

Notice that a voltage across a diode can't really be much higher above the Diode Voltage unless you have extreme amounts of current. On the other hand, there's nothing wrong with high negative voltage/reverse bias on a diode. So if you calculate both voltages that diodes could be pinning a node voltage to, determine which voltage would be valid for both diodes. In more sophisticated designs, you could apply this same rule to as many diodes as there are connected to a node.
[image]