# Which diode is conducting and what are the operation points of the conducting diode?

Tags: diodes

In the following circuit assuming that diode's cutoff voltage is \$0.7 V \$ , I want to find operating points (voltage, current) of diodes \$D_1,D_2\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWiQNL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My first guess is that DI=0FF and D2=ON.
Then I will have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT9BqO.png)</sup>

By applying KVL I have $$10V +I5kΩ -0.7V + I10KΩ +10 = 0$$ By solving with respect to \$I\$ we see that \$I=1.29mA\$

From this point how can I continue to find the operational points of the diodes???

**------------------------------------EDITED_1---------------------------------------**

My question was answered as you can see below it appears my first assumption was wrong.

My second guess is that \$D_1\$ is on and \$D_2\$ is off;

Then I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiBd4m.png)</sup>

By applying KVL I have $$-10V +I5kΩ +0.7V = 0$$ By solving with respect to \$I\$ we see that \$I=1.86mA\$

Then I will have:

\$V_{anode,d1}=0\$

\$V_{cathode,d1}=-10+IR1=-0.7 V\$

Where \$V_{cathode,d1}\$ is the voltage of node between the two diodes.

So now the main question, do these values hold true for our assumptions.

For D2 to be off, VD2<0.7 and \$V_{D2}=10V-I10KΩ-V_{cathode,d1}=10-18-(-0.7)=-7.3V\$

For D1, to be on VD1>=0.7 and \$V_{D1}=0−(−0.7)=0.7V\$

The math confirm our assumption So D1 is on and D2 is off!

**------------------------------------EDITED_2---------------------------------------**

As I was told my second guess was also wrong since there was a mistake in the math of D2.
D2 is assumed to be off so there is no current flowing through it and hence there is no current flowing through R2 and hence there is no voltage drop in the anode of D2. In the second guess \$V_{D2}=10V-V_{cathode,d1}=10-(-0.7)=10.7 > 0.7V when it was supposed to be <0.7\$ So I am going to make a third guess.

My third guess will be that D1=ON and D2=ON

Then my circuit will be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmJmar.png)</sup>

Then I apply Mesh current method to find I1 and I2:

$$I_1: 10V +I_15kΩ -0.7V = 0 => I_1=1.86mA$$

$$I_2: 0.7V -0.7V +I_210kΩ +10V = 0 => I_2=1mA$$

For D2 to be on, VD2>=0.7 and \$V_{D2}=10V-I_210KΩ-V_{cathode,d1}=10-10-(-0.7)=0.7\$

For D1, to be on VD1>=0.7 and \$V_{D1}=-10+5KΩI_1=0.7V\$

The math confirm our assumption So D1 is on and D2 is on! So probably the third guess was right!!

Comment: Are those voltage sources connected to ground?

Comment: in my schema I just have a small circle connected to R2 and says 10 V. But I din not know how to make this in the editor..

Likewise a small circle (-10 V) connected to R1

Comment: @DimitriC if you think that D2 conducts and D1 does not, show your work. We'll look at your work and see if what you did was correct or point you in the right direction.

Comment: @efox29 I tried to show some of my work but it is not much since I am not sure how to proceed!

Comment: See this quesiton, and read the answers. If you still don't understand, come back here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158019/diodes-in-parallel-circuit-analysis/158040#158040

Comment: @efox29 If I get it right D2 conducts and the voltage across is 10V-0.7V= 9.3V?? Is this the case?? 

What I don't understand is when I should add the cuttoff voltage and when I should substract the cuttoff voltage??

Comment: and then I apply KVL and I have V1-I(R1+R2)-Vd+V2=0? I solve with respect to I and this is how I find the current???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With diode analysis, one thing you have to be completely aware of is that it's a **guessing game**. Yes, I said guessing. How well you guess will depend on your experience, so even if you are the worst guesser ever, its ok, because the math will tell you.

When Vd >= 0.7, it conducts. When Vd < 0.7, it does not conduct. Vd is the is the difference between anode and cathode.

Now to the guessing game.

There are 4 cases to test.

- Case 1: D1 = OFF |  D2 = OFF
- Case 2: D1 = ON  |  D2 = OFF
- Case 3: D1 = OFF |  D2 = ON
- Case 4: D1 = ON |   D2 = ON

Your initial guess was that D2 conducts, and D1 does not. You didn't specify what your reasons were for that selection, but even if it was a blind guess, it does not matter because you'll need to prove your guess was correct. Don't ever guess, and not verify. Always verify your guess.

Case 3: D1 = OFF and D2 = ON

[image: schematic]

$$ -10V - 10k\Omega I + 0.7V - 5k\Omega I - 10V = 0 $$
$$ I = \frac{20V - 0.7V}{15k\Omega} = 1.28667mA $$

Lets look at the anode of D2
$$ 10V - (1.29mA)(10k\Omega) = -2.86667V $$

So let's look at the voltages at node between the two diodes.

$$ 5k\Omega I -10V = -3.6V$$

So now the main question, do these values hold true for our assumptions.

For D2 to be on, \$V_{D2} >=0.7\$ and \$V_{D2} = -2.9V - (-3.6) = 0.7\$

For D1, to  be off \$V_{D1} < 0.7 \$ and \$V_{D2} = 0-(-3.6V) = 3.6V \$

But.. D1 is supposed to be off...

Repeat the process for all cases until you can confirm that the math holds true with your assumptions.

But your initial guess that D2 is on, and D1 is off is wrong.

Comment: I think you have to flip the resistors in your solution... R2=10K and R1=5K.

Comment: Ya I copied it wrong, but it doesn't matter because I didn't use the designators in the solution. I used values.

Comment: You find the voltage on the anode of the v2 which is the voltage source connected to D2 minus the voltage drop because of the resistance.

Then you find the voltage at node between the two diodes which is the source connected (-10V) plus the voltage drop of the resistance. 

My question is : why do you subtract the voltage of the resistance in the first case and you add the voltage of the resistance is the second case??

Comment: 10V-(R1xI) is the voltage at the anode of the diode (or at the  positive terminal of V2. (5kxI)-10 is the voltage through that entire branch.

Comment: yeah I got that, my question is why you choose 5k*I-10 and not -5k*I-10?

Comment: Also can you please tell me if I want to inspect the case where I  have D1 on and D2 off then the circuit I will use to calculate the current is (-10V)----R1------(-0.7V) all in series?? D2 is like it is not there right??

Comment: What is the direction of the calculated current  ? I set the direction of the current as down. So you calculate voltages in the direction of the current established. I think you might need to review circuit analysis some more as well as what does a non conducting diode mean and what its representation looks like in a circuit.

Comment: But yes, D2 would not be there, if it was off.

Comment: I understand that the polarity of the resistances is fixed once you have selected the direction of the current. My confusion concerns the negative voltage sources and how I should handle them in KVL!!!

Comment: I tried to solve the assumption of D1=on and D2 = off in my question(edited). Can you please check and tell me if I am right?

Comment: On my phone. Rough look at it, it looks correct. I'll look a bit deeper when I'm near a computer. Don't change your question with additional edits because it throws all the answers out. You've modified your original question such that it's not even a question anymore, it's just you  doing work. Someone else reading this who is having similar problems will not understand the question and the answers that people provide. So don't edit your question and turn it into a solution.

Comment: ok, thanks. When it's convenient for you please check just to be sure it is ok and I did not have something wrong in my mind!!

Comment: @DimitriC is not right. The math for D1 is ok. But your math for D2 is not ok. If D2 is non conducting, then you interpret that branch as being open.

Comment: This question is now exceeding the original the question. I propose you either open a new question, or carry on in a chat. But do not modify the original question. My answer is already already deviates from your question now because you specified that you believe a certain condition, and now you changed your question to something else.

Comment: Should I change the question to my original end then add my second guess?? Can you please tell me what is wrong with the math for D2? I tried to follow the same steps as you followed in your answer??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24375/discussion-between-efox29-and-dimitri-c).

Comment: I edited my question to include the initial question plus I added all my work so far. I gave it a try in the case D1=0N and D2=ON. Can you please check if I got it right this time?? thanks!!1

Comment: @DimitriC its good. 3rd time it was.

Comment: Good. all math and circuit laws are good???